# Properties of measures on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{S}=\{E\subset X:E\text{ is countable or }X\setminus E\text{ is countable}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to find out which properties the measures $\mu$ on $(X,\mathcal{S})$, where $$\mathcal{S}=\{E\subset X:E\text{ is countable or }X\setminus E\text{ is countable}\}$$ have.

What I have done:

- In general we expect that $\mu(E_{countable})\leq\mu(E_{uncountable})$ since otherwise we would generate counterexamples like $X=\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ but $\mu(\mathbb{Q})>\mu(\mathbb{R})$.
- We cannot assign a non-zero constant measure to countable sets and a non-infinite measure to uncountable sets because otherwise we would generate counterexamples like the following: let $\{q_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ and consider that $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\{q_i\})=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(\{q_i\})=+\infty>\mu([0,1])$ but $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\{q_i\}\subset [0,1]$.

Now, all the measure I have seen on this $\sigma$-algebra **up to now usually** have, in accordance with what I have shown above, the form: $$\mu(E)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if $E$ is countable} \\ \text{number }\neq 0 & \text{ if }E\text{ is uncountable}\end{cases}$$

and I also think it should be possible to prove that such measures don't have the property that $\{\mu(E):E\in\mathcal{S}\}=[0,b],\ b\in\mathbb{R}, 0<b$.

Is this correct? Are there any other properties that characterize this $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Not all measures in the co-countable $\sigma$-algebra are of the form you suggest. Take the counting measure for example, i.e. $\mu(A)=n$ if $A\in\mathcal{S}$, and $A$ is finite with $n$-elements, and $\mu(A)=\infty$ otherwise.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you for your interest in my question; perhaps I didn't phrase it in a very clear way but I did not suggest that they cannot be of that form: in fact in the second bullet point I said that one cannot have a non-zero measure for countable sets without also having an infinite measure for the uncountable sets, just as the counting measure shows. After that I just noted that all the measures I have seen on this $\sigma$-algebra *up to now usually* have that form, but not that they cannot have any other form; in any case I have edited the question accordingly to remark this point.

Comment: I'd start with $X=\mathbb{Q}$ (for which it is easier to characterize all such measures) to see what properties are possible.  For instance, one can find a measure whose range is $[0,b]$ for any fixed $b>0$, and this measure extends naturally to $\mathbb{R}$ with the co-countable sigma-algebra.

Comment: @Lorenzo: Most examples of measures that I have seen on the $\sigma$-algebra in your posting have atoms. There are atomic measures whose values fill-up the space (see the following [posting](https://mathoverflow.net/q/15804/78591)) From this, I think it may be possible to cook-up a measure on the co-countable $\sigma$-albegra that fills an interval.

Comment: @BrianMoehring thank you for your interest in my question; maybe what I am about to say doesn't make any sense but if we set $X=\mathbb{Q} $ that should imply $\mathcal{S} =2^{\mathbb{Q}}$ and I don't see which kind of requirements that puts on a measure that could be extended to a measure on ($\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{S}) $.

Comment: @lorenzo I've added an answer to elaborate on my point, since it wouldn't fit in a comment and it answers the only concrete question you seem to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **$\sigma$-finite** measures $\mu$, there are at most countably many atoms.  That is,
$$A = \{a \in X : \mu(\{a\}) > 0\}$$
is at most countable.  Then $\mu$ has the form
$$\mu(E) = \sum_{a \in E \cap A} \mu(\{a\}) + \mu_{co}(E)$$
where $$\mu_{co}(E) = \begin{cases}0, & \text{if } E \text{ is countable} \\ c, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and $c \geq 0$ is some constant independent of $E$.

---

In particular, if we fix $b \geq 0$ and set $X = \mathbb{Q},$ then $\mathcal{S} = 2^\mathbb{Q}$. By enumerating $X = \{q_1, q_2, q_3, \ldots\}$, we may set $\mu(\{q_i\}) = 2^{-i}b$ and then we'd have $\{\mu(E) : E \in \mathcal{S}\} = [0,b].$

Further, while this particular $X$ simplifies $\mathcal{S}$, there's really nothing special about it.  This method can be used to find a $\mu$ whose range is $[0,b]$ for *any* infinite $X$ when using the co-countable $\sigma$-algebra (or more generally any measure space with an infinite $\sigma$-algebra).

---

I'm not sure what one can say precisely about $\mu$ when it's not $\sigma$-finite.